# Google search results won't open in new tab on mobile

Tags: google-chrome

I can't set where the results open anymore on mobile devices. On desktop I've set to open them in a new tab but on my iPhone they open in the same tab. I am logged in with the same account where I have that setting. I cannot access the particular setting on my phone though. It happens in all browsers so it must be a setting in the Google site, rather than in my browser.

I've been pulling my hair out since it happened in IOS 9 or so. Searched endlessly to no avail. I don't even know if it happens to others. It seems so rare that I can't even select an appropriate tag in this post so I had to choose google-chrome.

Comment: So I'm not the only one annoyed by this...

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue on Android and BlackBerry and this helps:

1. Navigate to google.com
2. In *Menu* check the *Desktop site* (or Request Desktop version)
3. Navigate bottom down on the re-rendered page and choose *Settings* -> *Search Settings*
4. Touch the *Open each selected result in a new browser window* in the *Where results open* group
5. Hit *Save*
6. Switch off the *Desktop Version* mode

Hope this helps.

Comment: This no longer works. It used to work but now on mobile it doesn't work anymore in the last week or so.